# SQL Server - How to display most recent records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in SQL Server.

```
ID PID LASTMODIFIED REASON
1  1   01/01/2011   XYZ
2  1   04/01/2011   XYY
3  2   05/01/2011   ZZZ
4  2   03/01/2011   ABC
```

I want to select the rows based on MAX(LASTMODIFIED) for each PID. For EX, the select should return the following:

```
ID PID LASTMODIFIED REASON
2  1   04/01/2011   XYY
3  2   05/01/2011   ZZZ
```

Pelase help me with the SQL statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.PID, A.LastModified, A.Reason 
FROM MyTable AS A INNER JOIN (
SELECT PID, MAX(LastModified) AS MaxDate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY PID) AS B ON A.PID = B.PID AND A.LastModified = B.MaxDate
```